# Can't print a simple JSON?

Tags: php

I know it's basic, but I couldn't get what's wrong because it's not my area.
I am sending some request to a server and print the response like this:

```
$rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_GET,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 $json = json_decode($response, true);

 echo $response;
```

Where I get this:

```
{"results":[{"Devices":["52401E7E-C5D7","AE80C0F8-999E","764BFD92-9753","78A23379-2C14","EEA03545-5EB9","E18DDFEC-C3C9"],"UserID":"433011AC-228A-4931-8700-4D050FA18FC1","createdAt":"2015-11-04T15:06:33.564Z","objectId":"3os7BGxRoG","updatedAt":"2015-11-04T17:08:57.635Z"}]}
```

Then, I am trying to print the JSON or its fields, but I then get nothing:

```
  echo $json;
  echo $json['UserID'];
  echo $json['Devices'];
```

Comment: `echo $json['results'][0]['Devices'];` and so on...

Comment: @Jan That wont' work, the first element is a stdClass type object. It needs to be `$json->results[0]->Devices[0/1/2/3/4/5/..etc]`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: No, he did cast it to an array (`json_decode($str, true)`)

Comment: @Jan You're right! my mistake.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No worries :-)

Comment: thank you all, but what is wrong with my "echo " ? why echo result works and the json is not ?

Comment: @AbraCadaver why echo will not work ?

Comment: It will if you know the structure and you get that with print_r()

Comment: @AbraCadaver i am not sure i get you, i don know the structure. Anyway, it works, but     print_r($json['UserID']); is not working. How do you get a field from that json ?

Comment: Have you read Abra's comment?

Comment: Yes sorry now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the comments a bit:

```
$str = '{"results":[{"Devices":["52401E7E-C5D7","AE80C0F8-999E","764BFD92-9753","78A23379-2C14","EEA03545-5EB9","E18DDFEC-C3C9"],"UserID":"433011AC-228A-4931-8700-4D050FA18FC1","createdAt":"2015-11-04T15:06:33.564Z","objectId":"3os7BGxRoG","updatedAt":"2015-11-04T17:08:57.635Z"}]}';
$json = json_decode($str, true); // to an associative array
// to echo the UserID
echo "userID : " . $json['results'][0]['UserID'];
// output: userID : 433011AC-228A-4931-8700-4D050FA18FC1

// to get the structure of the json array in general use print_r() as AbraCadaver pointed out
print_r($json);
```

In your attempt you were missing the `results[0]` part.

Comment: twice in a row indeed ! ;)